# c# .net override ToString for multiD array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015

I have a class that primarily provides a 2d array to its caller (after parsing a file).  It's returning this array fine, but I need to provide a way for that caller to convert that 2d array to a multi-delimited string.  pseudocode below.

Full disclosure:  Most of my time is scripting in other software, so I'm a bit rusty on OOP in reality, and especially in c#

I want the caller to be able to:

```
string[,] results;
getArray (arg1, arg2, etc, out results);
Debug.WriteLine(results.ToString(delim1, delim2));
```

but I'm not clear on how to create this override for ToString(), something like:

```
public override string[,] ToString(string rowSeparator, string columnSeparator)
{
    string retVal = "";
    for(int r = 0; r < this.getUpperBound(0); r ++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < this.getUpperBound(1); c++)
        {
            retVal += this[r,c];
            if (c + 1 < this.getUpperBound(1)) 
            {
                retVal += columnSeparator;
            }
        }
        if (r + 1 < this.getUpperBound(0))
        {
            retVal += rowSeparator;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `ToString` in your snippet code?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes.  Thanks for asking, I edited to show that

Comment: As an aside, if you're in control of `getArray` it would almost certainly be better to *return* that rather than using an `out` parameter, and follow .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not *overriding* anything - you're trying to *overload* the existing `ToString` method. It's a good job you're not trying to override anything, as you basically can't do that - you can only override members within a class declaration, and you can't declare the `string[,]` class yourself.

You can achieve your goal with an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(
        this string[,] array, string rowSeparator, string columnSeparator)
    {
        // Code as per your method, but using array instead of this
    }
}
```

Note that callers will need to have a `using` directive for the namespace containing `ArrayExtensions`, or a `using static` directive for the `ArrayExtensions` class itself, in order to use this as an extension method.

I'd also recommend using `StringBuilder` in your implementation instead of [repeated string concatenation](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html).

Comment: I assume you've got the right answer here, but I can't get the using directive right.  could you show a snippet from the caller?

Comment: @Keith: Well if `ArrayExtensions` is in a namespace of `Foo.Bar` you'd just need a using directive of `using Foo.Bar;`

Comment: Thanks Jon, that cleared it up because I'm actually sharing namespace here between the classes, so I didn't need the using directive.  final call is `results = res.ToString("\r\n", "\t");`.  unit test works, thanks!